# Is it safe to pass Linq and a .ToList(), .Single(), etc to another method as a func parameter?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, datacontext, func

I needed to wrap some Linq queries with some Retry Policy logic.

Is it safe to pass this:

```
return WithRetry<User>(() => 
   dataContext.Users.Where(u => u.UserID == userID).SingleOrDefault());
```

to this:

```
public TResult WithRetry<TResult>(Func<TResult> methodCall)
{ 
   // My Try/Catch Retry Code
}
```

Or should the first line be constructed like this instead:

```
return WithRetry<User>(() => 
{ 
     return dataContext.Users
                       .Where(u => u.UserID == userID)
                       .SingleOrDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Not sure how an array helps here?

Comment: It's not an array, the last snippet would wrap the linq in an anonymous function (I believe).

Comment: Ah, I see.  You would need to place `return` in front.  Either way, they seem to have the same type (`System.Func\`1[User]`) in my testing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I know the code compiles, but I didn't know if it would behave unpredictably in some way in regards to how the query was executed.

Comment: @Vyrotek: And what unpredictable result are you expecting?  Who can anticipate all the variables in your particular scenario?  Run some tests and see if it works!

Comment: Working a lot with `Resharper` results in seeing no difference between first and second code samples. I spent 5 minutes to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, if the argument type of a method is `Func`, calling it will automatically pass as a function without executing it.  You don't need to further wrap it in an anonymous function wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

The anonymous wrapper is not needed.  Just pass the lambda expression function call directly.